# convertir codigo js a scheme

Tags: java, scheme

Alguna manera de convertir este codigo java a scheme?

```js
import java.util.*;
class charges
{
    public static void main(String [] arg)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double charges=0,pb=0;
        
        System.out.println("Enter the total charges");
        charges=sc.nextDouble();
        
        if(charges<=500)
        {
            pb=(charges/100)*0.25;
        }
        else
        {
            pb=(500/100)*0.25;
            charges=charges-500;
            if(charges<=1000)
            {
                pb=pb+(charges/100)*0.50;
            }
            else
            {
                pb=pb+(1000/100)*0.50;
                charges=charges-1000;
                
                if(charges<=1000)
                {
                    pb=pb+(charges/100)*0.75;
                }
                else
                {
                    pb=pb+(1000/100)*0.75;
                    charges=charges-1000;
                
                    if(charges>=1)
                    {
                        pb=pb+(charges/100)*1.0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            
        System.out.println("Your Payback Amount is = "+pb);
    }
}
```

**Definicion de problema**
Algunas compañías de tarjetas de crédito devuelven una pequeña parte de los cargos que un
cliente durante un año. Una empresa devuelve

1. El 0,25% por los primeros 500 dólares de cargos,
2. 0,50% por los siguientes 1.000 dólares (es decir, la parte comprendida entre 500 y 1.500 dólares),
3. 0,75% para los siguientes 1.000 dólares (es decir, la parte comprendida entre 1.500 y 2.500 dólares),
4. y el 1,0% para todo lo que supere los 2.500 dólares.

Comment: Por favor, traduce completamente tu pregunta, estás en StackOverflow en español.

Comment: Listo! ya esta traducido

Comment: Que problema tuviste? Que investigaste? Cuéntanos un poco más de lo que te traba durante la conversión. Tal como está tu pregunta, pareciera que pides que lo convirtamos por ti. Por otro lado, la mejor manera de convertir un código de un lenguaje a otro es aprenderse ambos lenguajes.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (pay-back a)
(cond 
    ((<= a 500) (* a 0.0025))
    ((<= a 1500) (+ (* 500 0.0025) (*(-a 500) 0.005)))
    ((<= a 2500) (+ (* 500 0.0025) (* 1000 0.005) (* (-a 1500) 0.0075)))
    (else (+ (* 500 0.0025) (* 1000 0.005) (* 1000 0.0075) (* (-a 2500) 0.01)))

))
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).